# Loading axis2 modules from classpath

Tags: module, classpath, apache-axis, rampart

I am writing an Axis2 client which will not have access to a repository folder on the filesystem. Is there a way to load the modules which axis need for instance rampart and addressing, from the classpath.

Comment: No answer yet! Wow! It's that strange! I have seen quite a few similar problems on the other sites and no solid answer to their problem or mine.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the .mar files to the class path. Axis2 can pick the .mar files in the class path as module files.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install axis2 on your filesystem and add it's `lib` directory to the `CLASSPATH`. You can set it system wide or create batch/shell script to run your client. I prefer batch/shell script where I can also set some other options. With axis2 libs it can look like:

```
SET CLASSPATH=my_axis_client.jar;c:/axis2-1.5.1/lib/*
java -Dfile.encoding=utf8 yyy.zzz.my_axis_client
```

If you work on unix then instead of such

`SET CLASSPATH=...`

use

`export CLASSPATH=my_axis_client.jar:/my/axis/lib/*`

(be aware, on unix use `:` instead of `;` to separate directories in the `CLASSPATH`)